# How much an elective course FZ grade impact for PhD application?

Tags: phd

My career only goal is to get involved in research (PhD). My previous education, working experience (teaching) and publications help me to get admission in a Master program at a Canadian high ranked university. However unfortunately I got a FZ grade in one of an elective course (I was extremely mentally upset on the final exam day due to family issue) though I took another elective course to meet the programme requirement. While coming to PhD application, my supervisor informed me that my chances of not being accepted in the PhD program at the university is high since I have a FZ grade in my transcript. He also told me that he will write recommendation for me if I try to another university.
My question: can anyone please explain me how much does this FZ grade (though I have replaced the credit with another elective course) will impact in my PhD application in future?

Comment: Just try it. Sometimes (at least in the UK) researchers are just looking for someone that is ready to do the job, not someone that is excellent. In my opinion/experience, motivation is more important than intelligence to successfully finish a PhD, and at least *some* potential PhD supervisors will probably agree with me

Comment: What is this [FZ](http://www.zappa.com/) to which you refer? I think we have different interpretations of this set of initials.

Comment: Thank you! this FZ refers inadequate or simply Fail (below 70%) since it is a graduate level.

Comment: You can write a short explanation of the poor grade and include that in your application.

Comment: Than you so much! I will do so!